# Grep on a file to find a string between two words

Tags: python, python-3.x, grep, txt

I have a file named varout.txt, which contains a text as given below:

```
Message: unable to locate element
```

I have used the below command to fetching the text between the word **Message** and **element**:

```
result = subprocess.run(['grep -oP \'(?<(Message)).*(?= element)\' /home/ubuntu/varout.txt'],shell=True,capture_output=True)
reason = result.stdout
print(reason)
```

But I am getting below as my output:

```
b' : unable to locate`/n'
```

Where expected output should be as below, where I am going wrong ??

```
': unable to locate'
```

Comment: Looks like you made a small typo in the code, `(?<(Message))` must be `(?<=(Message))` in your codes, otherwise, you wouldn't have obtained any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the output as a byte string.

If you need to get the output as a Unicode string, decode the bytes:

```py
reason = result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

See the demo:

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run([r"grep -oP 'Message\s*\K.*?(?=\s*element)' /home/ubuntu/varout.txt"], shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
## => : unable to locate
```

I improved the regex a bit as follows:

- `Message` - matches a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*element)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and an `element` substring.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This was of great use.